# How can I show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and find the distribution of $Y$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

$X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ is an i.i.d. sequence of standard Gaussian random variables.

\begin{align}X&=\frac{1}{n}(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n) \\[0.2cm] Y&=(X_1-X)^2+(X_2-X)^2+\dots+(X_n-X)^2\end{align}

1. How can I show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?
2. How can I find the distribution of $Y$?

Can we use the following method to show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?
$$Cov(X,Y)=0$$

Or is there any other proper way?

Comment: In general, the covariance being zero will show that the two r.v.'s are *uncorrelated*, which does not mean they are independent. You have "independent implies uncorrelated," but the converse is false.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do my questions?

Comment: A way, most likely... An elegant, way, maybe... one that I see right now, unfortunately no.

Comment: If you can show that for any two real numbers $u$ and $v$ we have $E[e^{uX+vY}]=E[e^{uX}]E[e^{vY}]$ then independence follows from Kac's theorem.

Answer (score 5):

The variable $X$ is the sample mean and the variable $Y$ is the sample variance times $(n-1)$. So [Basu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basu's_theorem#Independence_of_sample_mean_and_sample_variance_of_a_normal_distribution) implies that they are independent.

The distribution of $Y$ is $\chi^2_{n-1}$ as the sum of the squares of the $n$ iid normal random variables $X_i-X$, (where $X$ is used and so there are $n-1$ degrees of freedom instead of $n$).

Answer (score 2):

${\bf X}=(X_1,\dots, X_n)^\prime$ has a multivariate
normal distribution with $\mu_{\bf X}=\mu {\bf 1}$ and $\Sigma_{\bf X}=\sigma^2 I$.
Here ${\bf 1}$ is the column vector of all $1$s, while $I$ is the
$n\times n$ identity matrix.

Let ${\bf e}_1=(1,0,0,\dots,0)^\prime $, and let  $A$ be the matrix of an orthogonal transformation
that takes the vector $\bf 1$ into the vector $\sqrt{n}\, {\bf e}_1$.

The vector ${\bf U}=A{\bf X}$ is  multivariate
normal with $\mu_{\bf U}=\mu \sqrt{n}\, {\bf e}_1 $
and $\Sigma_{\bf U}=\sigma^2 I$. In particular, the 
random variables $U_1,U_2,\dots, U_n$ are independent.

The first coordinate of the random vector $\bf U$ is
$$U_1=(A{\bf X})^\prime{\bf e}_1={\bf X}^\prime A^\prime {\bf e}_1=
{1\over \sqrt{n}}\, {\bf X}^\prime A^\prime A{\bf 1}
= {1\over \sqrt{n}}\, {\bf X}^\prime {\bf 1}=\sqrt{n}\,X.$$

Also, $$\sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i={\bf X}^\prime {\bf X}= {\bf X}^\prime A^\prime A {\bf X}={\bf U}^\prime{\bf  U}
=n X^2+\sum_{i=2}^n U_i^2,$$ so that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-X)^2 =\sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i-nX^2=\sum_{i=2}^n U_i^2.$$

The independence of $U_1$ and $\sum_{i=2}^n U_i^2$ implies the independence
of $X$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-X)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Partial solution here.

$Y$ is a quadratic form. In particular, let $\mathbf{1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector of ones, and define $$P_\mathbf{1} = \mathbf{1}\left(\mathbf{1}^{T}\mathbf{1}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{1}^{T} = \mathbf{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\mathbf{1}^{T}\text{.}$$
Let $$\mathbf{X}=\begin{bmatrix}
X_1 \\
X_2 \\
\vdots\\
X_n
\end{bmatrix}\text{.}$$
Then $$P_\mathbf{1}\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
X_1 \\
X_2 \\
\vdots\\
X_n
\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i = \mathbf{1}X = X\mathbf{1}\text{.}$$
Furthermore,
$$\begin{align}
Y &= \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-X)^2 \\
&= (\mathbf{X}-X\mathbf{1})^{T}(\mathbf{X}-X\mathbf{1}) \\
&= (\mathbf{X}-P_\mathbf{1}\mathbf{X})^{T}(\mathbf{x}-P_\mathbf{1}\mathbf{X}) \\
&= [(\mathbf{I}-P_{\mathbf{1}})\mathbf{X}]^{T}(\mathbf{I}-P_{\mathbf{1}})\mathbf{X} \\
&= \mathbf{X}^{T}(\mathbf{I}-P_{\mathbf{1}})^{T}(\mathbf{I}-P_{\mathbf{1}})\mathbf{X}\text{.}
\end{align}$$
$\mathbf{I}$ is obviously symmetric, and notice
$$P_{\mathbf{1}}^{T} = \left[\mathbf{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\mathbf{1}^{T}\right]^{T} = \mathbf{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\mathbf{1}^{T} = P_{\mathbf{1}}$$
so hence $P_{\mathbf{1}}$ is symmetric, so that $\mathbf{I}-P_{\mathbf{1}}$ is symmetric as well, and 
$$(\mathbf{I}-P_{\mathbf{1}})^{T} = \mathbf{I}-P_{\mathbf{1}}\text{.}$$
This gives $Y = \mathbf{X}^{T}(\mathbf{I}-P_{\mathbf{1}})^{2}\mathbf{X}$. Observe also that
$$P_\mathbf{1}^2 = \left(\mathbf{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\mathbf{1}^{T}\right)^2 = \mathbf{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\mathbf{1}^{T}\mathbf{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\mathbf{1}^{T} = \mathbf{1}\left(\dfrac{n}{n}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\mathbf{1}^{T} = \mathbf{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\mathbf{1}^{T} = P_{\mathbf{1}}$$
hence $P_{\mathbf{1}}$ is idempotent. Notice
$$(\mathbf{I}-P_{\mathbf{1}})^{2} = \mathbf{I}^2-2\mathbf{I}P_{\mathbf{1}}+P_{\mathbf{1}}^2 = \mathbf{I}-2P_{\mathbf{1}}+P_{\mathbf{1}} = \mathbf{I}-P_{\mathbf{1}}$$
since $P_{\mathbf{1}}^2 = P_{\mathbf{1}}$, as shown earlier. Hence $Y = \mathbf{X}^{T}(\mathbf{I}-P_{\mathbf{1}})\mathbf{X}$.

It can be shown that the rank of $\mathbf{I}-P_{\mathbf{1}}$ is $n - 1$. Using the theorem 7 [here](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~st849-1/lectures/Ch02.pdf) (p. 29), you can show that $$Y \sim \sigma^2\chi^2_{n-1}(\boldsymbol{\mu}^{\prime}(\mathbf{I}-P_{\mathbf{1}})\boldsymbol{\mu}^{\prime})$$
If
$$Q = \left(\mathbf{1}^{T}\mathbf{1}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{1}^{T} = \left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\mathbf{1}^{T}\text{.}$$
then $X = Q\mathbf{X}$.

For the remainder of the proof, see [this page](http://www.statlect.com/normal_distribution_quadratic_forms.htm#idn6), under "Examples."